# When calling JSON, getting "200 ok" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've gotten past all the other errors but now that I am successfully connecting to the page is says 200 OK error in firebug which of course is up there for least helpful errors.

```
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
     $(function(){
        $("a[href*='/site/apps/kb/cs/contactdisplay.asp']").click(function(e){
            var orgUrl = $(this).attr("href") + "&r=1";
           e.preventDefault();
           $.getJSON(orgUrl,
           function(data){
               $("placeholder").html("<strong>" + data.companyName + "</strong>");
           });
        });
     });
   });
</script>
```

Click on one of the company links on this and it will call the dynamic URL to grab the value from the destination:
http://www.kintera.org/site/apps/kb/cs/contactsearch.asp?c=biIQI0NJKiKYF&b=8383853&submit=submit

Will allow you to see what I am doing. I don't have control over the source html rendered but I was able to put the output I want to a json object. Now the trick is returning it.

Yes, the page it is calling from is in HTML but with a JSON object within it. As an example for the Workplace 6 link it pulls from this location: http://www.kintera.org/site/apps/kb/cs/contactdisplay.asp?c=biIQI0NJKiKYF&b=8383853&sid=efIOKYMEJhIKLYMxHkH&r=1. If you view the source you will see the JSON.

Comment: The 200 response means "success".  It's not an error.

Comment: It seems you are making a request from http to https: *"XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...]. Origin `https://www.kintera.org` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."* The other thing is that the requested URL returns HTML, not JSON. So `$.getJSON` won't work. You should be able to use `$.get` though. Maybe it helps you if you read again what JSON actually is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json. Could it be that you want a JavaScript object of some sort?

Comment: Where should `data.companyName` come from?

Comment: @FelixKling I remove the https from the equation since I need to do the basics first.

Comment: @FelixKling Now that the https I get a response but if you visit the URL it's calling as an example for the Workplace 6 link, yes it is an HTML page but with a JSON object within. http://www.kintera.org/site/apps/kb/cs/contactdisplay.asp?c=biIQI0NJKiKYF&b=8383853&sid=efIOKYMEJhIKLYMxHkH&r=1

Comment: MMh, that's not a JSON object. That looks like JavaScript inside an HTML comment. There is no easy way to get the data. You have to parse the HTML, get that comment node and parse (or eval) it's content. You are going a very hard way IMO, you should find a different solution for what you want to do.

Comment: I can change the format of the script including the comment but unfortunately cannot change the surrounding html because that is all apart of the proprietary CMS code. Would it be easier to remove the script and wrap the value (it's a merge field) with a div and class then do a .load() to grab it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem (from the link you posted) is that the href that you are getting from the link refers to `http://`…, rather than `https://` - these count as different origins, so the [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) rules will abort the ajax request and mark the request as 'cancelled' in your web console.

The other part is that the page that you are requesting doesn't return json. You'll want to have the target page respond with something like `{"companyName":"foo"}` with a mime-type of `application/json`.

Comment: Fixed it by converting it to a .load().

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing from JSON to .load(). For documentation purposes here's what I have ended up with.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Call for results
    $(function(){
        $("a[href*='/site/apps/kb/cs/contactdisplay.asp']").click(function(e){
            var orgUrl = $(this).attr("href") + "&r=1";
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get(orgUrl, function(data){
                $(".placeholder").html( $(data).find(".nameContainer").html());
            })
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This means I removed the code from JSON embedded in HTML to just HTML.